# Relatively Scale Text Based on Window Size While Supporting Browser Zoom

Tags: html, css

If I set my font size up in CSS to be based on the body/window size..

```
font-size: min( 1.5vh, 0.9vw );
```

..it works great, because the text shrinks as the smallest axis shrinks. However, it completely nullifies browser zoom, because I'm not using any absolute point sizes to set my font size. What would be the best way to do both of these? I've tried several mixups of `calc()` and `min()`, but browsers don't seem to enjoy multiplying pure numbers with `em` or `px` sizes.

Is there any way to pull this off? I don't need accurate scaling - I just want to give the user the ability to adjust the text size.

Comment: You can either go back to the old ways and use `rem` and media queries or you use a css var to set the base of your scale and let the user adjust it in a config somehwere

Comment: Well, I was about to use Javascript to add scaling buttons to my interface when I decided to make sure there were no "natural" options to let the Browser do it normally. I realized after posting that my HTML is slightly abnormal in the sense that its also height-fixed rather than just width-fixed. How would a user adjust a config file to change a CSS value? This is new for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a line of Javascript to set your own unit for font-size onload then you can define font-size relative to the initial vw/vh but declare it in px terms so it will scale if the user zooms.

For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font size test</title>
<style>
body {
  font-size: var(--font-size);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
This is some text
<script>
document.body.style.setProperty('--font-size', Math.min(0.9 * window.innerWidth / 100, 1.5 * window.innerHeight / 100) + 'px');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(You would need to add some sophistication to set the variable onload or a change of window size, not a zoom).